# ignore the following properties in swift Codable?

Tags: json, swift, codable, urlsession

I have this Account struct. I want to ignore the following properties environments and Id in encoding to JSON object when I send "POST" endpoint and use them return success decoding to swift object

update  I have this error Property type '[Environment]' does not match that of the 'wrappedValue' property of its wrapper type 'SkipEncode'

```
struct Account: Codable {
    let accountID, displayName, managedByID, id: String
    let environments: [Environment]
    let contacts: [Contact]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case accountID
        case displayName
        case managedID
        case id
        case environments
        case contacts
    }
}
```

Comment: when you say ignore, do you mean when encoding or when decoding?

Comment: ignore them in encoding to JSON object when I send "POST" endpoint  and use them return  success decoding to swift object

Comment: Unrelated, but you don't actually need `CodingKeys` here

Comment: I using CodingKeys to map to JSON properties' name are different

Comment: @NinjaDeveloper Not related to your question but your coding keys don't match the properties in your struct managedID != managedByID

Comment: I have this error Property type '[Environment]' does not match that of the 'wrappedValue' property of its wrapper type 'SkipEncode'

Comment: because Environment is a custom object

Comment: @NinjaDeveloper I think the easiest approach in this case is to create a custom encoder as proposed by Eric.

Comment: @NinjaDeveloper check my post below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to ignore, for example `environments` when encoding, you can define your own encoding implementation:

```swift
struct Account: Codable {
    let accountID, displayName, managedByID, id: String
    let environments: [Environment]
    let contacts: [Contact]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case accountID, displayName, managedByID, id, environments, contacts
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(accountID, forKey: .accountID)
        try container.encode(displayName, forKey: .displayName)
        // ... just don't include the environments here
    }
}
```

Comment: this is wrong the coding keys don't match the properties

Comment: @LeoDabus Can you elaborate please?

Comment: there is no managedID property. it should be managedByID

Comment: @LeoDabus Oh good catch, I missed that and I'll edit my answer now. I copied the code directly from the question.

Comment: you should change the coding key not the property name

Comment: Yea, but I felt like `managedByID` doesn't sound like a better property name than `managedID`. The first one sounds like a boolean as the second one sounds more like a string. Anyways, just my opinion, thanks for pointing out the error.

Comment: I would just remove the coding keys. You don't need them.

Answer (score 9):

Another approach, if you don't want to manually implement `encode(to:)` and give up on the benefits of `Codable` auto synthesis, you could create a property wrapper as a way of marking the properties you want to skip:

```
@propertyWrapper
struct SkipEncode<T> {
   var wrappedValue: T
}

extension SkipEncode: Decodable where T: Decodable {
   init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
      let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
      self.wrappedValue = try container.decode(T.self)
   }
}

extension SkipEncode: Encodable {
   func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
      // nothing to do here
   }
}

extension KeyedEncodingContainer {
   mutating func encode<T>(_ value: SkipEncode<T>, forKey key: K) throws {
      // overload, but do nothing
   }
}
```

Then you could just use `@SkipEncode` like so:

```
struct Account: Codable {
    let accountID, displayName, managedByID: String
    let contacts: [Contact]
    
    @SkipEncode
    let id: String

    @SkipEncode 
    let environments: [Environment]
}
```

Comment: `self.wrappedValue = try decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(String.self)`

Comment: Btw This is wrong you can't wrap environments it is not a string. You would need a generic property wrapper https://stackoverflow.com/a/64399046/2303865

Comment: Ah... shoot.. copy paste error Good catch, @LeoDabus.

Comment: Really? That didn't work for me for some reason... let me try

Comment: No.. you're right, it works.. Not sure what happened before. I was annoyed having to implement it :) so, good riddance

Comment: Haha.. I see you also added an answer sans all my mistakes

Comment: I am not sure if the decodable part would work as it is. It depends on the json OP is receiving

Comment: @LeoDabus, yeah I think that was it.. it didn't decode properly without the `init(from:)`. Adding it back

Comment: Yes my playground was buggy and indeed the generic decoding is needed

Comment: @LeoDabus, I made another minor change and removed the too-restrictive a constraint for `T: Decodable` in all cases.

Comment: I did think about leaving it generic as well but I though about OP asking only to not encode but keep decoding so I decided to constrain it to Decodable

Comment: @LeoDabus I'm trying to do the opposite of this and ignore the property wrapper from decoding. Any chance you could update the answer to include it?

Comment: @JoeBayLD, you should ask a separate question. Here's also something that might point you in the right direction: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/tips/default-decoding-values/

Answer (score 2):

Follow up in the approach suggested by NewDev. If you want to implement a property wrapper you would need to implement a generic one to be able to skip any property, not only strings:

```
@propertyWrapper
struct SkipEncode<T: Decodable> {
   var wrappedValue: T
}
```

---

```
extension SkipEncode: Codable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
       wrappedValue = try decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(T.self)
    }
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws { }
}
```

---

```
extension KeyedEncodingContainer {
    mutating func encode<T>(_ value: SkipEncode<T>, forKey key: K) throws { }
}
```

---

Playground testing:

struct Environment: Codable { }
struct Contact: Codable { }

```
struct Account: Codable {
    let accountID, displayName, managedByID: String

    @SkipEncode
    var id: String

    @SkipEncode
    var environments: [Environment]
    
    let contacts: [Contact]
}
```

---

```
let account = Account.init(accountID: "account", displayName: "name", managedByID: "manager", id: "id", environments: [], contacts: [])
let dt = try JSONEncoder().encode(account)
print(String.init(data: dt, encoding: .utf8)!) // {"accountID":"account","contacts":[],"managedByID":"manager","displayName":"name"}
```